# Why is my directives module not being included in my Angular app module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just learning Angular and I'm encountering a few issues with module resolution. In `js/directives/directives.js` I have the following directive scoped to a `directives` module:

```
angular.module("directives").directive("selectList", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function() {
            // do stuff 
        }
    }
});
```

On my webpage:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module("editUserApp", ["directives"])
        .controller("editUserController", ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
            // do stuff here 
        }]
    );
</script>
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module editUserApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module directives due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'directives' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Now, obviously, `editUserApp` cannot know where `directives` is, all by itself, so how do I tell it to fetch the directives.js file? Do I have to include it in a script tag (which doesn't seem very scalable)?

I need some way to import directives to my angular app. How can I do this?

Comment: The only problem which I can see is that you have not created/registered the module 'directive' but you are trying to access it. Better you create/register the module first like  `angular.module("directives", [])`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
angular.module("directives" ,[])
```

in your first block

```
angular.module("directives")
```

tries to find an existing module called directives

---

If you are looking for a way to import these files on a as needed basis, you might want to look at http://requirejs.org/ or http://browserify.org/ or similar tools.

Comment: Same error, even with the change. I'm not asking about dependency injection here, I'm asking about dependency resolution. If "directives" is in another file, I cannot access it if it is not included in my main webpage, yes?

Comment: Yes, you need to include it in a script include in your main webpage to access it. When you say `it's not very scalable`, do you mean the network load times? Because if your directives.js has no cache busting on it, it's going to be got from the server once and every other call in the same browser session is going to come from the local cache.

Comment: Angular will recognize modules if don't correctly. None of my code is in the same file. What @potatopeelings is talking about is directives have a setter: `angular.module('directives', [])` which will create the module and a getter `angular.module('directives')` which you can use to access it later. You need to set it: `angular.module('directives', []).directive(...)` and then in your main module `angular.module('editUserApp', ['directives'])

Comment: TjGeinger, yep, but you're still including the files on your main app right with a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your js/directives/directives.js file into your html and remove the directives dependency on your App module.

your code should be :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module("editUserApp", [])
        .controller("editUserController", ['$http','directives', '$scope', function($http, $scope,directives) {
            // do stuff here 
        }]
    );
    </script>
```

Comment: So say I have 12 directives and 5 controllers. I have to include all of them? That does not sound scalable at all.

Comment: concat all your directives into one file :), you can use Grunt to do it easily

Comment: Yep, I'm using Gulp at the moment, so I'll take a look into that.

Comment: Wait, why does my directives module need to be injected into the controller? What's wrong with making it a dependency of editUserApp?